# How to customize Android Studio's import ordering in Kotlin to ignore whether they are "static" imports?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, import

Using the "Optimize Imports" in Android Studio 3.4.1, the imports are ordered similar to this:

```
import com.walla.walla
import com.willy.willy
import org.koin.android.ext.android.get
import org.koin.androidx.viewmodel.ext.android.viewModel
import kotlin.concurrent.thread // <-- note this line
import kotlin.random.Random
```

As you can see above, function (a.k.a. "static" import in Java) imports like `kotlin.concurrent.thread` and  `kotlin.random.Random` are put under other imports.

It is not consistent with the [Android Kotlin style guide](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/style-guide):

> Import statements for classes, functions, and properties are grouped together in a single list and ASCII sorted.

I couldn't find a way to make it such that Android Studio order imports irrespective of whether the import is a class or a function. Is there an option to make it so?

Comment: After try to import many dependency to class, I see that `import java...` and `import kotlin...` **always** in bottom (`ASCII sorted` itself). Another import on top is in ASCII sorted (look correct follow the document). Still don't know why all import is not in ASCII sorted @@

Answer (score 11):

This seems to be a misunderstanding. In fact, [`kotlin.concurrent.thread`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.concurrent/thread.html) *is* a function. Therefore, it should be grouped together with the other classes.

**UPDATE:** I do see that the latest version of IntelliJ *2019.1* (and Android Studio) might not be able to conform to the [Android Kotlin style guide](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/style-guide#import_statements). If you have these import statements, then IntelliJ does not sort strictly by ASCII:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils
import java.util.Base64
import kotlin.concurrent.thread
```

Instead, IntelliJ orders them as:

1. Third-party
2. Java
3. Kotlin

I do not see a way to configure IntelliJ or Android Studio to sort them this way:

```
import java.util.Base64
import kotlin.concurrent.thread
import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils
```

Perhaps you should submit some feedback to IntelliJ or [the authors of the Android Kotlin style guide](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=192697).

Comment: Yes, sorry about the misunderstanding. What I meant by "static" import was indeed function import. The question is how to make AS _not_ put function imports under class imports.

Comment: using companion object in kotlin ?

Comment: @RandySugianto'Yuku', I've updated my answer. I do not think there is a solution with the current versions of IntelliJ and Android Studio. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Goto Help , Find Action and type Optimize Imports or press Ctrl+Alt+O